# Why is a brownian motion conditioned to stay positive a Bessel-3

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am told this result long ago but I still don't know how to prove it. Is it because that this conditioning can be turned into a Girsanov probability change? Or is there any simpler ways to see it?

Comment: Notice that $P(\min_{0 \leq s \leq t}B_s \geq 0) = 0$, so you have to say what you mean by saying "Brownian motion conditioned to stay positive."  In the usual interpretation, this result is Pitman's 2M-B theorem.  You can find a number of proofs of that result.